# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in bin\magento:30

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, third-party-module, cli

I wanted to install a new extension in my store and I keep on getting this error in CLI.

```
An exception was raised while creating "Application"; no instance returned#0 Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'a
pplication', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
Sites\XXXXX\bin\magento(21): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#7 {main}

An exception was raised while creating "Request"; no instance returned#0 Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'reque
st', 'Request')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('request', 'Request')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Request', 'request')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Request')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Service\ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager))
[internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'application', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
Sites\XXXXX\vendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
Sites\XXXXX\bin\magento(21): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in D:\Sites\XXXXXX\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayObject.php on line 426#0 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\composer\ClassLoader
.php(444): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, '"continue" targ...', 'D:\\Sites\\xxx...', 426, Array)
#1 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#2 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('D:\\Sites\\xxx...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Zend\\Stdlib\\Arr...')
#4 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\Parameters.php(29): spl_autoload_call('Zend\\Stdlib\\Arr...')
#5 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-console\src\Request.php(96): Zend\Stdlib\Parameters->__construct()
#6 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-console\src\Request.php(122): Zend\Console\Request->getParams()
#7 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-console\src\Request.php(66): Zend\Console\Request->params()
#8 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Service\RequestFactory.php(29): Zend\Console\Request->__construct()
#9 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\RequestFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'request', 'Request')
#10 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'request', 'Request')
#11 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'request', 'Request')
#12 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('request', 'Request')
#13 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Request', 'request')
#14 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#15 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(113): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Request')
#16 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Service\ApplicationFactory.php(29): Zend\Mvc\Application->__construct(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager))
#17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ApplicationFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#18 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'application', 'Application')
#19 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1097): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'application', 'Application')
#20 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('application', 'Application')
#21 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Application', 'application')
#22 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#23 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(261): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Application')
#24 D:\Sites\XXXXXXvendor\magento\framework\Console\Cli.php(57): Zend\Mvc\Application::init(Array)
#25 D:\Sites\XXXXXXbin\magento(21): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#26 {main}


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in D:\Sites\XXXXXXbin\magento:30
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in D:\Sites\XXXXXXbin\magento on line 30
```

I did Remove the extension from \app\code but this issue remains. I can't run any Magento CMDs. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the generated files might solve it, try to run these sequence of commands below. Check the [server requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html) too.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer ;
rm -rf vendor/* generated/* var/* pub/static/* ;
composer install ;
php bin/magento setup:upgrade ;
```

Comment: By running the first cmd, won't it break the website if it did that update? I don't want to update nor upgrade this version of Magento. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It won't update the Magento version, it'll update the core components, fixing issues and adding improvements, with no updates in the Magento version. If there is some manual change in the core it will fix it.

Comment: I did that and the website is dow shows error "Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under the application root directory." when I run composer install I keep on getting this error "$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
  [ErrorException]

Comment: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "
  continue 2"?
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] ....." any advice?

Comment: I did an update to my composer since it is asking for that.  And when i run the cmd composer install.  I get the error :  Problem 1
    - Installation request for colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.1 -> satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.1].
    - colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract v1.1 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
I don't really wanna mess with downgrading or updating my php version.  I am using an older version of magento and don't want to upgrade it. Thank you.

Comment: The best scenario will be downgrading your PHP, it won't mess up anything, the initial issue was caused just because of this incompatibility, you Magento version don't support PHP 7.3

Comment: Thank you so much, Rafael.  I have done the downgrade to the php, and I confirm it shows 5.3 in my php ini file;  however, in CLI it remains PHP 7.3.7 (CLI).  Any thoughts? I did try to downgrade it but no success.  Please note I am using IIS.

Comment: @Notsobad I highly recommend adjusting the server to run in the Magento's server requirements. requirements

Comment: @Rafeal, I got it to work and run the command composer install which ran successfully.  The cmd line errors are gone.  But I am facing this issue, of stylesheets and javascript are not applied and it shows errors in the console.  I also run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy with no luck. I am looking around to resolve this.  Have you faced this before?  Thanks in advance mate.

Comment: yes @Notsobad, when the server is not running using Magento's requirements it causes a lot of problems. You can set it to run in developer mode in the app/etc/env.php when it's using 'production' you can change to 'developer', so you don't need to generate the static content.

Comment: @Rafeal, Thank you, I got my environment working properly. I also got my CLI to work with the correct version of PHP.  Thanks for the help.  You rock man.